# how to replace quickblox service with firebase

Tags: android, q-municate

I used source code of Q-municate app to build chatting app ,
source code in github : https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android
I want to use firebase service like : authentication phone,  Cloud Messaging , push notification in my app and remove quickblox service . 
How can I do that ? 
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBlox team is going to start this migration in Q-municate Android in 2 weeks

Meanwhile, QuickBlox team released Firebase API in SDKs,
more info here https://quickblox.com/blog/firebase-phone-authentication/

so you can start on your own